# Reliable connection with Azure SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I developing a C# application that storing data in Azure SQL Database.

As you probably know, Azure SQL Database is placed somewhere on the Internet. Not over LAN network (but this question also relevant for reliable network like LAN).

I've noticed that from time-to-time that I'm getting errors like "Connection is closed" (or another network errors). It's really easy to simulate this with [Clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/). The reasons for those errors are bad network conditions.

So, my first idea to solve this is "try again". When I getting this error, I simply try again and then it's working good. Like a magic.

This maybe solving the problem, but, *open another kind of problems*. Not all the situations are good with this solution. I'll explain:

I'll separate the scenarios for two types:

1. Retry cant make any damage - operation like SELECT or DELETE. Retrying will have the same expected result. So, with this type of problems - my solution is working fine!
2. Insert or Update - retry will damage the information.

I'll focus the the point **number 2**. For example, let's say I have:

- A users table. Columns in this table: ID, UserName, Credits.
- Store Procedure that make the user (by user id) pay some of his credits.

The "Pay" Stored Procedure is:

```
UPDATE tblUsers SET [Credits] -= @requestedCredits WHERE ID=@ID
```

Calling the SP is tricky problem:

- If this will work without problem - we are fine.
- If it will fail, we don't know whether the operation is done on the DB or not. Retrying here can lead to that the user will *pay twice*!

So, "Retry" strategy here is not an option.

### Solutions I'm thought on:

I'm though to solve this problem by adding a "VersionID" for each row. My SP now:

```
UPDATE tblUsers SET [Credits] -= @requestedCredits, VersionId=NEWID() WHERE ID=@ID AND VersionID=@OldVersionId
```

Before making the user Pay(), I'll check the VersionID (Random GUID) and if this GUID wasn't changed after network failure while paying, I'll try again (proof that the data wasn't changed on the DB). If this VersionId changed, so the user is paid for the service.

The **problem** is when I using multiple machines at same time, this making this solution problematic. Because another instance maybe made a Pay() on the version-id and I'll think that my change is executed by me (which wrong).

What to do?

Comment: Have a look at rowversion. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx This is a reliable way to ensure row consistency for inserts and updates.

Comment: Not solve the problem. For example, if i got exception while "Pay()", and the rowversion tell that 2+ modification executed, I'm cannot know if it was me or another user that made it exactly with me.

Comment: If you have a transaction going I don't expect any confusion. if the commit succeeds you're database is in the correct state, if the commit fails it gets rolledback either by you or  by the server and you can then retry the complete transaction.

Comment: The problem that I'm not sure if the DB server got my request or not. The network failure can be on my request or server's response.

Comment: It's impossible to manage a single db from multiple machines. is it possible to partition the users so that any user will be handled by a single machine?

Comment: Have you looked about using a Transaction ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are making SQL queries from a local/on-premise/remote (i.e. non-Azure property) to a SQL Azure database.

Some of the possible mechanisms of dealing with this are

- **Azure hosted data access layer with API**

  Consider creating a thin data access layer API hosted on Azure WebApp or VM to be called from the remote machine. This API service can interact with SQL Azure reliably.

  SQL is more sensitive to timeout and network issues than say a HTTP endpoint. Especially if your queries involve transfer of large amounts of data.
- **Configure an increased timeout**

  The database access mechanism being used by the C# application is not specified in the question. Many libraries or functions for data access allow you to specify an increased timeout for the connection.
- **Virtual Private Network**

  Azure allows you to you create a site-to-site or point-to-site VPN with better network connectivity. However, this is the least preferred mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You never blindly retry. In case of error you **read current state** then re-apply the logic and then write the new state. What 'apply the logic' means will differ from case to case. Present the user again with the form, refresh a web page, run a method in your business logic, anything really.

The gist of it is that you can never simply retry the operation w/o first reloading the persisted state. The only truth is what's in the DB and the error is big warning that your cached state is stale.